# tokenSeparators in Select2

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

Thanks in advance, two things:

1- How can i take "Enter" and "Tab" keys as token in Select2?

This is some of the code i have.

```
            $("#ListaValores").val($("#ListaValores").val().replace(/\;/g,','))
        $("#ListaValores").select2({
            tags: true,
            tokenSeparators: [';'],
            maximumResultsForSearch: -1,
            dropdownCss: {display:'none'},
        });
```

First line is just transforming the input so the data can be used by Select2.

Original Input can be sth like this:

```
$("#ListaValores").val("value1;value2;value3")
```

These values are stored in a db and are loaded to a textbox that is then transformed to a select2.

Everything is working as expect, but i would like to transform this part:

```
tokenSeparators: [';']
```

so it also accepts "Enter" and "Tab" keys as token.

Can someone help? I tried ASCII codes but no luck.

2- Plus, is there any tag to disable the spinner image?
(since there is no data being loaded i don't really need a loading image appearing)

UPDATE 2:

I had some success with this:

```
$("#s2id_ListaValores").on('keyup', function(e) {
            if(e.keyCode === 13){
                $("#ListaValores").val($("#ListaValores").val() + ';' + $("#s2id_autogen1").val())
            }
        });
```

But $("#s2id_autogen1").val() is not static and is always changing, so this kind of works once... plus, i would still need to update the results displayed. I can do it with with a "refresh" on the select2 div but then the div changes it's id, and the $("#s2id_ListaValores").on('keyup', function(e) event will not work.

Comment: Enter is automatically works as token separator if you set multiple and tags to allow using some values: <select multiple="multiple"></select>.

Comment: There is an [open issue](https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/3359) on github's select2 repo to add this feature: by now, you cannot.

Comment: As i said before, i managed to go around the issue. In the code i left here you just need to include a regex for it to handle the id change automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by recursion function:

```
//init select2 field:
initMultiSelect(tSel);

function initMultiSelect(tSel) {
        tSel.select2('destroy');
        tSel.select2({
            tags: true,
            tokenSeparators: [',', ' ', ';'],
            dropdownCss: {display:'none'}
        });

        //manual add new values by Enter
        (function (t) {
            $('#s2id_' + t.attr('id')).on('keyup', function(e) {
                if(e.keyCode === 13){
                    //add new value
                    t.val(t.val() + ',' + $('#s2id_' + t.attr('id') + ' input ').val());

                    //refresh select2
                    initMultiSelect(t);

                    //get focus to select2 last position
                    t.select2("close");
                    t.select2("open");
                }
            });
        })(tSel);
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may solve the question, including an explanation of *how* and *why* this solves the problem [would really help](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: This answer uses the same idea as my update in the original post. Just with an alternative to the use of regex.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, when pasting, This is impossible in the current version of select2, because it uses an input type="text" as it's input field, and newlines are stripped on paste by the browser.

In order to make this work, select2 will need to be patched to use a textarea instead. I have a Pull Request open that accomplishes this, which you can view here: https://github.com/select2/select2/pull/4795 If/when my pull request is merged in, you should be able to use the specified characters as tokenSeparators, but until that happens, you can download my fork to fix your issue if you would like.

Answer (score -3):

Try using the following as token separators for the "enter" and "tab" keys.

```
tokenSeparators: [';', '\n', '\t']
```

The "enter" key will normally trigger a selection by Select2, but a newline ("enter" key in a different program") will not. You can use `\n` to indicate to Select2 that these should also be treated as separators.

The same appears to the tab key, which should normally select the currently highlighted value, and uses `\t` as a separator when it is being loaded from another source.

Keep in mind that this difference only really matters when you are pasting in data that needs to be tokenized, as Select2 has bindings for these two keys that will automatically tokenize them already. You may need to enable `tags` though in order for that to happen.

Comment: \n - work, but I test on Ubuntu, what about Windows?